# How to go back to the immediate parent in XPath and get the text?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

My `xpath` is

```
//div[contains(@class,'ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable')]//div[@class='ui-widget-content slick-row odd' or @class='ui-widget-content slick-row even']/div/input[contains(@id,'custProglabel')]
```

I need to access `div` just before `input` tag and get its text. I tried using:

```
By.Xpath(//input[contains(@id,'custProglabel')]/preceding-sibling::div).getText();
```

I have many elements like this and only the content of my input tag changes. So based on the content I am trying to access the immediate div and get its text.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get immediate parent using `..`

```
By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'custProglabel')]/..")
```

As a side note, `xpath` should start with lower case 'x'.

Comment: It worked!! xpath upper case was a typo.sorry for that.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than drop down to `input` and come back up to `div`, consider
using a predicate on `div`

```
//div[input/@id='custProglabel']
```

or any element

```
//*[input/@id='custProglabel']
```

Also, note that `contains()` could mistakenly match `custProglabel2` or `MYcustProglabel`, so it's better to use equality test here.

Comment: Why would selecting the parent having the child `//*[*/@id='id']` be better than selecting the parent of the child `//*[@id='id']/..` ? Is there any rational reason?

Comment: I don't have a preference, I was just wondering if there were a specific reason like better performance or less side effects since you wrote "isn't really ideal".

Comment: It's more subtle than that phase implies, so I'll grant you the point.   Answer updated.

Comment: @kjhughes,@Florent B - Actually I have a list of elements with similar path and the input id is the only attribute that changes. But the word "custProglabel" remains constant in the input id attribute. I need to click and select few elements from the list and caputre their text. What I am doing is : Access the input id attribute and click on it. Traverse back to its parent div and capture text. Repeat the steps in a for loop. So by the end I have few elements that received the click and their text.

Answer (score 3):

use below xpath:

```
//div[contains(@class,'ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable')]//div[@class='ui-widget-content slick-row odd' or @class='ui-widget-content slick-row even']/div/input[contains(@id,'custProglabel')]/parent::div
```